# What does it mean double free detected in tcache 2 while using mpz?

Tags: c++, memory, rsa, gmp, alloc

I use this program to store a mpz value but when I add a 0 (
400000000000000000000000000000000000000 instead of 40000000000000000000000000000000000000 -> 38 0s instead of 37) I get

> free(): double free detected in tcache 2
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(const int argc, const char * const argv[])
{
char *str= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
mpz_class l;
l=40000000000000000000000000000000000000_mpz;
mpz_set_str(l.get_mpz_t(), str, 10);
cout<<endl<<str;
return 0;
}
```

Is there a possibility to store large numbers?

Thank you

Comment: How should I declare str? Only after I read the arguments I can find out how long the "message is". Is there a way to declare only a pointer?

Comment: This is a common problem when working with C-style strings. If you don't know how big a message could be, you're usually best off assuming the worst case and allocating for the biggest possible message. Since this is now a statically-sized allocation, consider using an automatic variable. For example, consider using `char str[1024];` in place of `char *str= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);`. Fewer memory management headaches in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code has undefined behaviour because you are trying to assign `l` from an uninitialised array `str`.

I'm guessing you got your functions confused and meant to write the opposite

```
mpz_get_str(str, 10, l.get_mpz_t());
```

That code assigns `l` to `str`.

Use the following code to work out how big `str` needs to be

```
size_t size = mpz_sizeinbase(l.get_mpz_t(), 10) + 2;
```

Comment: Here's an explanation for the `+ 2` part: "_The right amount of allocation is normally two more than the value returned by `mpz_sizeinbase`, one extra for a minus sign and one for the null-terminator._"